# Disappearance of all cell outputs of a jupyter notebook in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a big problem. All cell outputs my Jupyter notebook in Google Colab are deleted. I do not know why, if I accidentally pressed "Restart and run all" or something similar. 
Is there any way to restore the state of the notebook from this disappearance of the cell outputs?

Can someone help me? Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the revision history using the File -> Revision history menu.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly old, but adding an answer here anyway. If it doesn't appear in the revision history there you can refresh the page at which the notebooks are present, and the output should reappear even if you had previously cleared it.